# Flutterflow - set a container height equal to another container height

Tags: flutterflow

I have two containers that are side by side. The one on the left contains nothing. It just has a different colour. I want to set the height of the container on the left equal to the height of the container on the right. How can I do that? Here is a picture of the layout in Flutterflow:

[image]